# How do I change the desktop background from command line?

Tags: command-line, desktop-background

How can I change my desktop background from command line?

Comment: See the thread [Changin desktop background from the command line](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-346375.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change desktop background from command line in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Edit:** In later versions of Ubuntu (this question was written in 2011, after all), things moved to gsettings. See: [How to change desktop background from command line in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity)

---

It's a `gconf` setting: `/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename`. You can set its value by running the following:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename <path>
```

Obviously, replace `<path>` with a full path to the background image you want to display.

If you want to see what else is available from a nice GUI, run:

```
gconf-editor /desktop/gnome/background/
```

Comment: I did this with gconf-editor but nothing changed. I'm assuming it will when I restart things, but I'd rather not have to close everything to try out a new background. Is there a way to get it to refresh immediately?