# Setting Desktop Wallpaper via Terminal

Tags: 11.04, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the desktop background from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50019/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-background-from-command-line)

Is it possible to set the desktop wallpaper in ubuntu 11.04 via a terminal command? I've been searching for about two hours but didn't find anything related to this. 
In Ubuntu 10.04 I did it with

```
gconftool-2 -t str --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename
```

but it doesn't work with 11.04.

Comment: Where is the exact duplicate please?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is this one here ;)
the second one doesn't work, the key is set correct, but it doesn't has any effect on the background. when i change the wallpaper in the appearence tool, the key isn't changed
is there a way to see which keys are changed by an application?

Edit: Oh, it was my fault. I ran the commands as root, not as normal user. Sry for the trouble.

"gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename --type string" still works