# Setting desktop background with gconftool-2

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change desktop background from command line in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity)

gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /path/file.jpg

doesn't work. It changes the variable but the background doesn't change.

gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename

outputs the file that I set for desktop background. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to put the complete address of the file not just the name

Comment: I also tested it with an absolute path. It still doesn't work.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811571