# Multiple Unity Launcher Side Panels?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to duplicate the default left side Unity panel and have another one on the right? I have multiple applications that I want to lock to the launcher and I don't like continuously scrolling to the end of the left panel.

I know a simpler alternative would be to simply use the main Unity launcher fixed on the top, but I was just curious to know if multiple side panels was possible.

Comment: I don't think a second launcher is possible (not sure though), but you might really be interested in the answers to this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/118332/367990

Comment: Haha. Read it already during my initial Google search for this problem. Thanks anyway.