# Set desktop background from command line over ssh

Tags: unity, ssh, desktop-background, .desktop, gsettings

I am attempting to set my desktop background from the command line in ubuntu 12.04.

I am able to do this from the terminal on the actual machine as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/my/image.png
```

However when I login to the machine over ssh and run the same command, I am presented with the following error:

```
ben@base:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/my/image.png

** (process:19940): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=ca5602075c1f96df6beebf670000000b --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

** (process:19940): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=ca5602075c1f96df6beebf670000000b --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
```

How can I set the desktop over ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is `X11 initialization failed`. Graphics programs find the display screen through the '$DISPLAY' environment variable. Ssh does not propagate '$DISPLAY' by default, `ssh -X` gets you your own X session and sets '$DISPLAY'. but that is not the answer. Perhaps if you had done `xhost +inet:remotesystem` on the server first... See `man xhost`, and `SEE ALSO
       X(7), Xsecurity(7), Xserver(1), xdm(1), xauth(1),`

I think you are doomed to failure, unless you want to read a whole lot of man pages.

Comment: I know you can do this, I used to prank my coworkers. The answer has to be in Xsccurity

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell gsettings what display you want to set the configuration on. Since you likely want to change the setting on the *remote* system, so for example the default display is:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```