# Unable to change desktop background using gsettings in Unity

Tags: desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 14 Unity. I am unable to change my wallpaper from the terminal.
Instead of the wallpaper the lock screen pic is changed. I typed this in the terminal by referring this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/prasad/Pictures/Wallpapers/cry.jpg'
```

Comment: Did you try to log out / in? When I try, it works perfectly.

Comment: You mean that after login / out it works?

Comment: yes it does. weird but effective solution.

Comment: Now that is a nice solution ;)