# Sliding Desktop Wallpapers into Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: desktop-environments

How can we get an automatic desktop background image changing, over an specific time, into Lubuntu 15.10?

I am interested in something like the typical slide presentation, with a, let's say, 5 seconds between each slide.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the wallpaper with:

```
pcmanfm -w /home/user/path/to/picture.jpg
```

Here they made an script for gnome:
https://askubuntu.com/a/510135/287964

You can adapt it as:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/home/indra/Pictures/wallpapers"
PIC=$(ls $DIR/* | shuf -n1)
pcmanfm -w $PIC
```

... and then set the cron job, or run a infinite 'while' loop with a 'sleep'.