# ubuntu 14.04 wifi and Ethernet doesn't works

Tags: wireless, ethernet

i've just install Ubuntu 14.04 from a key on my computer, I have already installed 5 time ubuntu on other computer, but for this one, i can't connect to internet at all...

And i have try every solution i could find on internet !

So,  first of all, ubuntu doesn't find any wifi connection, so i try to connect to Ethernet:
Wired connection 1 doesn't work...

I try this:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

it say:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 

   802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
   Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
   Kernel_driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

i don't know what is it... so let's try another solution, when i set these following line:

```
lspci -n | egrep '0200|0280' | awk '{print$3}'
```

it say:

```
1969:10a0
14e4:4365
```

So I try to do these following line:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf #its ok if this command does nothing or fails
sudo modprobe b44
```

But the first line fails, the second too, and the third seems to works.. (but i'm not sure there are no outputs...)

**EDIT:**
i did what suggested here:
[How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

first i cp `pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_XXXXX.deb` and `pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_XXXXX.deb` from my key in my home, then i did `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Then i download this: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (64-BIT DRIVER FROM UBUNTU REPOSITORY) and I retry dpkg again: not working... (reboot done)

Here is my screenshot:
(after trying to dpkg the 2 .deb in my bottable key, i download the 64BIT-DRIVER in an other key and i retry like I said to dkpg the downloaded one)

[image: dpkg *.deb the 64bit driver]

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, it seems i have installed a wrong version...
How can i remove driver i've just downloaded ?

So I recap:
I have from my key bootable ubuntu 14.04:

```
dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-Oubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

and from the answer here: [How to change desktop background from command line in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity) i have these one:

```
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-Oubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb
```

I have the 4 of them in my desktop... i think i install the 4 of them... how can i know which one i have, how can i delete the one i don't need ?

Thanks !

Comment: i did what you tell in this post: first i cp `pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_XXXXX.deb` and `pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_XXXXX.deb` from my key in my home, then i did `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
Then i download the 64-BIT DRIVER FROM UBUNTU REPOSITORY (with your link) and I retry dpkg again: not working... (reboot done)

Comment: Did you replace XXXX with the real file name?

Comment: Please add information to your question, not to comments.

Comment: You have 14.04.2. You need to remove the driver you copied from the installation disk and download another one as directed in the answer. http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb

Comment: You install a wrong version. It does not build.